# Is it possible to recover an HSQLDB from the data file alone

Tags: teamcity, hsqldb

A delete *.* was executed on the folder containing a HSQLDB. The only file which was locked by the system (and thus not deleted) was the database.data file. Is it possible to recover the database from this file alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the delete was done within the `BuildServer` directory itself and not specifically within the `BuildServer/system` directory you are out of luck since all the builds and their build step configurations are stored within `BuildServer/config/projects`.

The Database only stores build logs, changes, users and etc. but not the actual config. They are all XML based configs on the file system.

If the delete was done within `BuildServer/system` you may be able to start up a clean TC Instance to rebuild the `BuildServer/system` directory and then shut it down. Once its down switch out the `buildserver.data` files and bring it up again. (Trying to do this now but its taking forever to start up. If I find out more I'll edit).